# Mocha flow control after assertion fails

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I think mocha stops running the current test case after assertion fails, like this

```
it('test', function(done) {
    a.should.equal(b);
    //if a is not equal to be, won't go here
    //do something
    done();
}
```

I need to continue doing something after assertion fails, I tried to use try...catch, but there is no "else" for catch, so if I do

```
try {
    a.should.equal(b)
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
    done(e)
} finally {
    //do something
    done()
}
```

this will call done() twice, so I have to add a flag,

```
var flag = true;
try {
    a.should.equal(b)
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
    flag = false
    done(e)
} finally {
    //do something
    if(flag)
        done()
}
```

I think this is so complicated, so I wonder if there is an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `after` hook will still get called when a test fails, so you can place your test inside a context that has such a hook:

```
describe('suite', function() {

  after(function(done) {
    // do something
    done();
  });

  it('test', function(done) {
    a.should.equal(b);
    done();
  }

});
```

Comment: actually I'd like to do it after each test case finishes, so I may use afterEach(), but the "do something" differs from each test case, so I don't think I can use this.

Comment: @KemingZeng you can nest `describe` blocks, so you could create one for each test, and have a separate `after` hook for each.

Comment: I use another way to do it, but I think after hook should be a good solution to this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is being called twice is because the `catch` is handling the exception, but the `finally` block will *always* execute regardless of if the assertion throws an error.

Use `return` to handle your scenario - if an exception is caught it will return done with the error, otherwise it will skip the catch and just `return done()`.

```
try {
    // test assertion
    a.should.equal(b)
} catch(e) {
    // catch the error and return it
    console.log(e)
    return done(e)
}
// just return normally
return done()
```

If you need to use it in an if/else scenario you can handle it with a variable.

```
var theError = false;
try {
    // test assertion
    a.should.equal(b)
} catch(e) {
    // indicate we caught an error
    console.log(e)
    theError = e
}

if (theError) {
    // there was an exception
    done(theError)
} else {
    // no exceptions!
    done()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think the first would be easier. So mocha doesn't have anything for this?

Comment: Mocha does have something for this - see the two examples :) It's just a library like anything else, you still have to write javascript around it.

Comment: I meant for both of my examples to be valid, however each might be more appropriate based on the specific situation. You'll need to design for your specific needs.

Comment: Got it, I thought maybe there are more "mocha" way to do it, but that's fine, this is pretty good solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the finally will be executed either it fails or doesn't fail. That is why it executes the done twice.

```
You can do:

    try {
        a.should.equal(b)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
        done(e)
    } 
    done()
```

If it fails you will exit through the catch, otherwise you keep going and return normally.

Answer (score 0):

The test runner's job to decide if it should bail or continue to test the other tests in the suite.
If you want tests to continue running remove the `--bail` from your `mocha.opts`
https://mochajs.org/api/mocha